# Android error : appt exited with code 11 on adding new dependency to build.gradle

Tags: android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, aide-ide

I am usuing aide to learn and develop android app.
Recently i have been facing this error ;: appt exited with code 11 when i add any new dependency to my build.gradle
I have added already 9 dependencues and this error is getting displayed for the 10th one whether it may be any dependency
If i remove that dependency and rebild the project the error is gone
Dont know what the error is
Need help!

Answer (score 1):

**Follow this simple steps to recover this error:**

> **Method 1:**

```
-Go to File->project structure->Project
-Check Android plugin Version and change it to 1.3.0(Latest one)
-Go to File->project structure->app->Properties->Build Tools Version
-Change it to latest one. Also do this for any other module you have for your project.
-Clean and build project.
```

**Note:** If your build tool version is less than 22.0.1 then you may still face same error while gradle build so please update your SDK from SDK Manager to latest one then restart android studio and follow above steps.

> **Method 2:**

```
-If you don't want to update build tools version or you don't have latest SDK version just Go to File->project structure->Project.
-Check Android plugin Version and change it to 1.0.0(Older one)
-Clean and build project.
```

I recommended Method 1.

Comment: Appreciate 5our answer but i am not using android studio ivam using AIDE on android